# In Python with Pycharm An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters

Tags: python

I'm new to automation. I have found Pycharm for mac.

When I execute the code, I receive the message: "An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters" no matter what parameter I use.

my code:

```
# coding=utf-8
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver.get('http://www.google.com')
search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search_box.send_keys('Python')
search_box.submit()
search_box = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Welcome to Python.org')
search_box.click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: I don't have Safari webDriver, but it works fine with Chrome. Can you share complete stacktrace?

Comment: HI Andersson, but in the Chrome doesn't works because I try even in firefox but out other issues who I need to gekodriver but I have install. than you very much for the comment